# How to Integrate AEM with React JS?

Tags: reactjs, aem, aem-6

I need to integrate AEM with React JS to use react as a front end and AEM for receiving data.

Tried to follow some tutorials but did not got the solution Also need steps to understand react component integration with AEM component

Answer (score 0):

You should first be generating the project using [AEM archetype](https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype) and pass `frontendModule` value as `react`. This will setup the baseline project for you to use AEM SPA editor with React implementation.

Once deployed this will give you text and title component implementation in AEM. Post this you can follow the AEM react development guidelines for your project. Refer to Adobe's documentation [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-with-aem-headless/spa-editor/react/overview.html?lang=en)